# Image recognition services

Tags: image-recognition

I'm now current making a mobile application. I want to find a service which I'll upload image of my defined objects : Airplane, computer, ... and when users use the app, they take a picture of the object I already defined in service, the service will tell him/her about the object information, such as: Akai's computer, Akai's laptop, ...

I wonder if there is any image recognition which provides database for inputting images as sample data with information to help me to achieve or not.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

There is an important tradeoff here at play.  There are two scenarios:

- You have relatively **few categories** (objects for which the user can take an image) and **multiple example images** for each category. You have plenty of options from the realm of machine learning (**neural network** frameworks like *caffe* or *Tensorflow*). But if you want things to work with **relatively small number of examples** (you should still have at least tens per category), the easiest way is to use an external API like [vize.it](http://vize.it/) where you can set up the categories via a web interface and **have the image recognizer hosted externally** and accessed via a REST API.
- You have **many categories** and just one or a **few examples** for each category. I'm personally not aware of any pre-made solutions to such a problem.  My approach would be to use *a pre-trained convolutional neural network* to process the images, using the *hidden representation* near the top of such network (very much like what is used e.g. on the image side of [automated image captioning](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/sfmltalk.pdf) - [example code](https://github.com/karpathy/neuraltalk2)), and train a classifier that takes a pair of images processed this way and outputs a *[0,1]* scalar that represents how close the images are.  I have [experimented with that approach](https://github.com/brmson/dataset-sts) for comparing sentences and that works pretty well, but I expect you will need a big dataset.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of vize.it.

Answer (score 0):

> when users use the app, they take a picture of the object I already defined in service, the service will tell him/her about the object information, such as: Akai's computer, Akai's laptop, ...

Since your user is trying to identify an instance of an object, and retreive metadata about it, the Watson Visual Recognition service's **similarity search** feature may be a good fit.  It is a beta service, which is free for the time being.

You can add photos with associated metadata (like strings "Akai's computer") into a collection, which indexes the images by their visual appearance.  You can then query the collection with the "find_similar" method to retrieve the image ids and metadata from the most visually similar images.

Here is a demo:  https://similarity-search-demo.mybluemix.net/  That page also includes a link to the API reference.  Watson VR also includes custom classifier training, which you might find interesting.